# SQL - Field Grouping and temporary data restructruing

Tags: sql, vb.net

I would like to apologize first about my title, because I understand it may be technically incorrect

I currently have a database with multiple tables, 4 of them are relevant in this example.

```
FORMS
FIELDS
ENTRIES
VALUES
```

Below is a shortened version of the tables

```
Create table Form_Master
(
form_id int identity primary key ,
form_name varchar(255) ,
form_description varchar(255),
form_create_date date ,
)

Create table Field_Master
(field_id int identity primary key,
form_ID int foreign key references Form_Master(form_id),
field_name varchar(255),
type_ID int
)

Create table Entry_Master
(
entry_id int identity primary key,
entry_date date,
form_id int foreign key references Form_Master(form_id),
)

Create table Value_Master
(
value_id int identity primary key,
value varchar(255),
field_id int foreign key references Field_Master(field_id),
entry_id int foreign key references Entry_Master(entry_id),
)
```

The purpose of these tables is to create a dynamic method of capturing and retrieving information - a form is a table, a field is a column, and entry is a row and a value is a cell

Currently when I am retrieving information from a form, I create a temporary table, with columns as such in the field_master, then select all entries linked to the form, and the values linked to those entries, and insert them into the temporary table I have just created.

The reason for the temporary table is to restructure the data into an organised format and display it in a `DataGridView`.

My problem is one of performance, creating the table as mentioned above is becoming slower as forms exceed fields > 20 or entries linked to a form exceeds > 100

My questions are:

Is there a way to select the data directly from field_master in the format of the temporary table mentioned above?

Do you think I should re-think my database design?

Is there an easier method to do what I am trying to do?

Any input will be appreciated, I do know how to use Google, however in this instance I am not sure what exactly to look for, so even a keyword would be nice.

Comment: Can you show as the code that you are creating the temporary table. It is not clear if you create it, in the database or in VB

Comment: Hello - I create and populate the table into the same database as mentioned above - I do execute the create and inserts from my application into my database. There is a lot of code used, must I post all of it ?